# How to remove specific rows in R?

Tags: r

A data set I'm using is the following:

```
    C1  C2  C3  R1
R1  NA  NA  NA   5 
R2  NA  NA  0.4  7
R3  0.1     NA   6
R4  NA  NA  NA   2
```

From the data frame, I want to remove rows that contain numbers which is larger than zero from C1 to C3.

The final outcome must be:

```
    C1  C2  C3  R1
R1  NA  NA  NA   5
R4  NA  NA  NA   2
```

I tried with:

```
df<- df %>% filter_at(vars('C1' : 'C2`), all_vars(. > 0))
```

but I got en error with this. How Can I fix it?

Imported from Excel:
[image]

Wrote in R:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `rowSums` in base R :

```
cols <- paste0('C', 1:3)  
df[rowSums(df[cols] > 0, na.rm = TRUE) == 0, ]
```

Or using `filter_at` :

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% filter_at(vars(C1:C3), all_vars(. <= 0 | is.na(.)))

#   C1 C2 C3 R1
#R1 NA NA NA  5
#R4 NA NA NA  2
```

and `filter_at` has been deprecated so you can write this with `across` as :

```
df %>% filter(across(C1:C3, ~. <= 0 | is.na(.)))
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(C1 = c(NA, NA, 0.1, NA), C2 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA
), C3 = c(NA, 0.4, NA, NA), R1 = c(5L, 7L, 6L, 2L)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c("R1", "R2", "R3", "R4"))
```

Comment: Thank you Ronak. I got an error saying: "Error in env_bind_lazy(private$bindings, !!!set_names(promises, names_bindings)) " My data set is imported from Excel. Is it because of the original file? I used last option.

Comment: That's a weird error. Can you restart R and try again? If it still does not work add `dput(head(df))` to your original post. I updated my answer with the data that I am using and it works without any error. Can you try the answer with the data in my answer?

Comment: You are right. It works with your codes. The data I wrote is not a real one. My data structure may wrong. This is the error: Error in env_bind_lazy(private$bindings, !!!set_names(promises, names_bindings)) :

Comment: I posted pictures of two data frame. "NA"s look different. Is it because of this?

Comment: You can check if the `NA`'s are real `NA`s or character `"NA"`. Pictures will not help unfortunately since we cannot use it to test the solution. Can you add data as `dput` ? If there are lot of columns and rows you can only add `dput(df[1:5, 1:5])`

Comment: "c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_), c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, ". Original data is too big, so I just copied this.

Comment: structure(list(Tickers_L = c("Adj Close", "Adj Close", "Adj Close", 
"Adj Close", "Adj Close"), Adjusted = c("A", "AA", "AAN", "AAP", 
"AAT"), Adjust_40 = c(36.893303, 21.658623, 24.977247, 197.68248, 
37.676949), Adjust_39 = c(36.587368, 22.154621, 25.646193, 196.025101, 
37.226849), Adjust_38 = c(36.654289, 22.225704, 25.646193, 196.656494, 
36.141285)), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: structure(list(Tickers_S = c("A", "AA", "AAN", "AAP", "AAT"), 
    `2015-10-30_S` = c("NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA"), `2015-11-02_S` = c("NA", 
    "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA"), `2015-11-03_S` = c("NA", "NA", "NA", 
    "NA", "NA"), `2015-11-04_S` = c("NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA"
    )), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))

Comment: the last one is from the file imported from Excel

Comment: Yes, you have character `NA`'s. You need something like `df1 %>% filter(across(\`2015-10-30_S\`:\`2015-11-04_S\`, ~. <= 0 | . == 'NA'))`

Comment: Hm.. there is still same errors.  Can you just let me know how to change all NAs to zero?

Comment: I would suggest to turn those character `NA`'s to real `NA` by doing `df1[df1 == 'NA'] <- NA`. The above solution would work as it is then. If you want to turn them to 0 you can do `df1[df1 == 'NA'] <- 0`

Comment: Thank you Ronak. I changed NAs as real NA. There is still same error, but it might be my mistake. I'll go over my codes and data frame. Thank you!!

Comment: I just want to let you know that it was because one of column names of my data frame was missing. After I modify it, it perfectly works. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

A more manual approach is as follows:

```
df <- as.data.table(df)

if(length(which(df$C1 > 0)) > 0){df <- df[-(which(df$C1 > 0)),]}
if(length(which(df$C2 > 0)) > 0){df <- df[-(which(df$C2 > 0)),]}
if(length(which(df$C3 > 0)) > 0){df <- df[-(which(df$C3 > 0)),]}
```